# Installing phpMyAdmin in MacOS 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, osx-yosemite

I recently installed `mysql-5.6.26-osx10.8-x86_64` in a Yosemite (MacOS 10.10.5) environment. In order to perform this installation I allowed myself to be guided by several online entries dedicated to this purpose.

I was told to find a file called `mysql.sock`. I even created a database for the `$ sudo locate` command to find it and still I could not. So, I installed the launch option in the MySQL package that I had downloaded from the Oracle website that I had been told not to install. I searched again, and still I was not able to find the file `mysql.sock`. What I did discover was the following:

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

I also found a set of instructions that told me to modify this file.  Reluctant to modify something that I do not understand simply because I am told to do it, I am writing to you.

**Please find below an original copy of the above file, as well as a copy of the recommended alterations. Please provide your own recommendation as to how I should proceed before installing phpMyAdmin.**

Oracle Installation

```
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>ExitTimeOut</key>
    <integer>600</integer>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>_mysql</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld</string>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <false/>
    <key>ProcessType</key>
    <string>Interactive</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld</string>
        <string>--user=_mysql</string>
        <string>--basedir=/usr/local/mysql</string>
        <string>--datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data</string>
        <string>--plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin</string>
        <string>--log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err</string>
        <string>--pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid</string>
        <string>--port=3307</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>SessionCreate</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>_mysql</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/usr/local/mysql</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Suggested Modification Obtained Online from an Independent Source:  http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/

```
  <dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true />
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mysql.mysqld</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
      <string>--user=mysql</string>
    </array>        
  </dict>
</plist>
```

After the above modification it is recommended that I perform the following additional changes:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

Finally, according to the MySQL panel in Yosemite’s PREFERENCE panel I already have the ability to start and restart MySQL automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It is a lot better to install XAMPP from Apache Friends to avoid all this hassle, it now comes with the new PHP 5.6; this is the link: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: I prefer to create my own stack, as I can better customize it to my own needs.  Thanks.